# Lambda -> Atlas connection timeout (private subnet - peering)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas, aws-vpc-peering

We have 1 Atlas cluster that is already peered to 1 VPC in 1 region (eu-west-1). This peering connection has worked fine for years. At the moment, I'm trying to setup another peering connection to another VPC we have in another region (eu-west-2).

The peering connection has been established fine (the latter one on the screenshot below):

[image]

...and the SG has been whitelisted...

[image]

So, as far as I'm aware, everything seems fine on the Atlas side of things.

In AWS, we have the VPC *(vpc-0ac2d...)* with an IPv4 CIDR of 172.16.0.0/16. The peering connection looks fine as well:

[image]

The VPC has 2 Route Tables associated with it; *rt-main-pub* & *rt-main-priv*. The former having 3 public subnets & the latter having 2 private subnets.

Public routes below:

[image]

...& private routes:

[image]

The NAT *(nat-03b...)* is sitting in the public subnet so all traffic routed through there to the IGW & hit the wider internet. Apart from IPs that fall within the range of the Atlas CIDR which are routed to the peering connection *(pcx-0d7...)*

I have a test lambda which is doing just some HTTP request which succeeds so I know that the NAT -> IGW setup is working.

[image]

^^ that's my lambda config. In the correct VPC & the 2 private subnets.

And the rules on the SG *(sg-05782b...)* are...

[image]

[image]

I've compared all this to the setup that we currently have & I really can't see any differences. Logically, this seems like it should work but the lambda connection times out to the cluster.

It's also worth nothing that I can connect fine to the cluster with the Mongo URI connection string that I'm using.